# Delete an existing shader or program (or get its Id to do so)

Tags: opengl, shader

I have a compiled shader or program (not sure of the correct term) and I need to delete it.

How do I find the Id of compiled programs and/or shaders to do so?

I know it exists because the debugger tells me that I am trying to redefine it, and cannot compile it again because of this:

```
ERROR: 0:1: error(#198) Redefinition at_coord_Y
ERROR: 1:1: error(#248) Function already has a body main
```

The first line of the shaders source is:

```
"in float at_coord_Y;"
```

Can I somehow use this to find the Id?

EDIT 1: Hopefully to clarify a bit, the shader fails to compile because it already exists.

```
    GLint compiled = UNDEFINED_VALUE;

    const GLchar* shaderSrc[] = {
        "in float at_coord_Y;",
        "void main()",
        "{",
              // Dont mind the empty space
        "}"
    };

    GLuint shaderId = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(shaderId, glNumberOfLines(shaderSrc), shaderSrc, NULL);

    glCompileShader(shaderId);  // Fail to compile because it already exists. Redefinition error.

    glGetShaderiv(shaderId), GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled); // Compile status GL_FALSE
```

But how can I find the Id of an existing shader (or program)?

Comment: "*I have a compiled shader or program (not sure of the correct term) and I need to delete it.*" If you're not sure about what it's called, then you're probably not sure about what you're doing at all. And you're certainly not sure enough to know that you need to delete something. So at the very least show us the code that's causing the problem (both the shader code and the code compiling and linking it).

Comment: I am not sure you understand OpenGL. What i need to do is detach this shader from the programs it is linked to (I can find out if it is linked to any programs by calling delete on the shader, if it is not it will be deleted). However I need to somehow find its Id, which I do not have, to do so. Now I know "at_coord_Y" is the shader source, but can I use it to find the Id? Or can I somehow just list all programs or something (propably not). If I can just find the program Id, the documentation says that when calling delete on the program, they will be automatically detached. I just need the Ids

Comment: Did not mean to sound offensive with the first sentence, sorry. I meant "I am not sure you understand what my problem is".

Comment: "*can I use it to find the Id?*" Given what? Are you trying to find one shader object anywhere, or some shader that's attached to a known program? Also, you should put that information into your question, not the comments. Use the "edit" button.

Comment: Sorry Nicol, thanks for trying to help tho. I do not really understand how this works as you can deduct. I am assuming that if the shader was not linked to a program, it would be deleted. But since it still exists (as per the redefinition error) I am assuming that it is linked to a program. I do not have the Id of the shader or the program which I need to do anything in OpenGL. How can I find them? Can I somehow just flush the memory to delete this existing shader?

Comment: @user1166780: I'm pretty sure Niceol Bolas understands OpenGL very well. Hint: Take a look at who's the top answering  users in the OpenGL tag on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/opengl/topusers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are completely misunderstanding the error. OpenGL isn't saying that the *shader object* (what you get with `glCreateShader`) is already defined. It's saying that there is a problem in your *shader's text* (what you passed with `glShaderSource`).

There are many problems with your shader loading. I have no idea where you got this loading code from, but I strongly advise avoiding that place.

[`glShaderSource`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glShaderSource) takes multiple strings, yes. But that *doesn't* mean you throw every line into a separate string. It's supposed to be used for "headers" and the like. Which means that the compiler will *concatenate* all of the strings together when compiling them.

In general, unless you're using the extra strings as headers to prefix onto your main shader, just pass an array of *one string*. Save yourself the pain.

Also, you didn't use [a `#version` directive](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Core_Language#Version). Without specifying a version, you're forced to use GLSL 1.10. And in GLSL 1.10, `in float at_coord_Y;` is not a legal definition.